# Problema con directiva ng-repeat AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-repeat

Tengo un problema con la directiva `ng-repeat` de **AngularJS**, estoy creando un componente de banner que funciona de la siguiente manera: al dar clic en agregar imagen se convierte dicha imagen a `base64` y se agrega la imagen nueva a un `array` y es con este `array` que se hace el recorrido del `ng-repeat`. El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
<div class="img" ng-repeat="imagen in imagenes track by $index">
    <div class="cont_img">
        <img src="{{ imagen.imagen }}" alt="" class="img-responsive imagen">
    </div>
</div>
```

y en el Controller:

```
$scope.imagenes = [];
$scope.cambioUpload = function($file){
    var reader  = new FileReader();

    reader.readAsDataURL($file.value[0]);

    var dataURL = '';

    reader.onload = function(){
        dataURL = reader.result;  

        $scope.imagenes.push({
            temporal : $scope.imagenes.length + 1,
            imagen: dataURL,
            tiempo: 0
        });
    }                
}
```

El problema es que la imagen nueva que fue agregada no se actualiza en tiempo real, aparece únicamente al dar clic en cualquier lugar de la página, no se por que está sucediendo esto.

Comment: No se que pueda pasar si cambias el nombre de tu ng-repeat "imagen", ejemplo: nombre in imagenes, y usa {{nombre.imagen}}. Cuentame si te sigue saliendo el error, no se si es por el mismo nombre que estas usando y no sabe cual escoger.

Comment: Sigue igual, no se por que solo se ve el cambio al dar clic en cualquier parte del sitio, de hecho hago una consola de $scope.imagenes y me muestra que el array tiene datos pero el ng-repeat no los agrega automáticamente :c

Comment: Interesante, sigo analizando tu caso. :)

Comment: Acabo de descubrir algo, si saco el push de la funcion reader.onload me actualiza en tiempo real pero con la imagen vacía (obviamente por que no esta recibiendo dataURL), creo que el problema entonces va a ser el onload. cómo más podría hacer esa parte?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es porque agregando el elemento fuera del ciclo [`$digest`](https://elabismodenull.wordpress.com/2015/03/26/watch-y-digest-entendiendo-el-servicio-scope-de-angularjs/) de angular.

Cuando se ejecuta la funcion `$scope.cambioUpload`, todo modelo que se actualize entre el inicio y final de la funcion sera actualizado en la vista.
Ahora bien, el evento `FileReader#onload` rompe esa regla ya su ejecucion comienza cuando la imagen carga, lo que significa que ya la ejecucion del metodo `$scope.cambioUpload` ha terminado. En otra palabras: su ejecucion es asincrona. Y como ya el $digest ha terminado, no se actualizaran los cambios en la vista hasta que se ejecute otro `$digest`.

Esto es lo que pasa en tu caso:

```
se ejecuta funcion $scope.cambioUpload
  se activa el $digest
   se inicializa instancia FileReader()
    se agrega evento onload a instancia FileReader()
     termina ejecucion metodo $scope.cambioUpload
      termina $digest y actuliza la vista
   ..
   ..
   se ejecuta el metodo onload()
    agrega elemento a la coleccion
     finaliza ejecucion onload()
```

Fíjate que en el caso de onload, no se ejecuta $digest para actualizar la vista. por lo que tienes que forzar el `$digest` con `$apply()` para que actualize la vista una vez se ejecute el metodo `onload`:

```
reader.onload = function(){ 

    // forzamos a que angular actualize la vista manualmente.
    $scope.$apply(function(){ 
         $scope.imagenes.push({
            temporal : $scope.imagenes.length + 1,
            imagen: dataURL,
            tiempo: 0
         });
   });

}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, esto resolvió el problema inmediatamente, muy buena la explicación, gracias !!! :D

Comment: Con la actualización que hiciste me quedó aún más claro, muchas gracias por tu gran ayuda !